# Can a Byte[] Array be written to a file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write out a  `Byte[]` array representing a complete file to a file.

The original file from the client is sent via TCP and then received by a server. The received stream is read to a byte array and then sent to be processed by this class.

This is mainly to ensure that the receiving `TCPClient` is ready for the next stream and separate the receiving end from the processing end.

The `FileStream` class does not take a byte array as an argument or another Stream object ( which does allow you to write bytes to it).

I'm aiming to get the processing done by a different thread from the original ( the one with the TCPClient).

I don't know how to implement this, what should I try?

Answer (score 840, accepted):

Based on the first sentence of the question: *"I'm trying to write out a Byte[] array **representing a complete file** to a file."*

The path of least resistance would be:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
```

Documented here:

> [`System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx)

Answer (score 46):

You can use a `BinaryWriter` object.

```
protected bool SaveData(string FileName, byte[] Data)
{
    BinaryWriter Writer = null;
    string Name = @"C:\temp\yourfile.name";

    try
    {
        // Create a new stream to write to the file
        Writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(Name));

        // Writer raw data                
        Writer.Write(Data);
        Writer.Flush();
        Writer.Close();
    }
    catch 
    {
        //...
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Edit:** Oops, forgot the `finally` part... lets say it is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: Lets say, I have received compressed data, and I have decompressed it to Byte[]. Is it possible to create the file back using above function ? Any tutorial or demo online ?

Comment: @buffer_overflow: You would need to compress it first if you want to get the original file back. Have a look at the Decorator Pattern for a possible implementation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: `BinaryWriter` is disposable so should probably be used within an `using` block. That'd also mean you could probably leave off some of the extra calls since the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs,51545ac4b683f454) shows that it does some cleanup while disposing.

Comment: Why swallow the exception and return true/false? Daft.

Answer (score 24):

There is a static method `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes`

Answer (score 13):

You can do this using `System.IO.BinaryWriter` which takes a Stream so:

```
var bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("path",FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
bw.Write(byteArray);
```

Comment: Just want to add , after write add bw.flush and bw.close

Comment: @dekdev: There is no point in calling `Flush()` before `Close()` as `Close()` will flush. Even better is to use a `using` clause which will also flush'n'close.

Comment: Do not forget to use the Dispose;

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [FileStream.Write(byte[] array, int offset, int count)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write.aspx) method to write it out.

If your array name is "myArray" the code would be.

```
myStream.Write(myArray, 0, myArray.count);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yep, why not?

```
fs.Write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, there is also an `async` version of the `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()` method:

```
Task WriteAllBytesAsync (
    string path, byte[] bytes,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

Example usage (in an `async` method):

```
await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("C:\\Test.png", bytes);
```

Note that since writing to a file is an IO operation, as a general rule it must be performed asynchronously not to block the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Try BinaryReader:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert the Binary AnyFile to Byte[] format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static byte[] ConvertANYFileToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream);
    imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)image.ContentLength);
    return imageBytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Asp.net (c#)**

// This is server path, where application is hosted.

```
var path = @"C:\Websites\mywebsite\profiles\";
```

//file in bytes array

```
var imageBytes = client.DownloadData(imagePath);
```

//file extension

```
var fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(imagePath);
```

//writing(saving) the files on given path. Appending employee id as file name and file extension.

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path + dataTable.Rows[0]["empid"].ToString() + fileExtension, imageBytes);
```

**Next Step:**

You may need to Provide access to profile folder for iis user.

1. right click on profile folder
2. go to security tab
3. click "Edit",
4. give full control to "IIS_IUSRS" (IF THIS USER NOT EXISTS THEN CLICK ON ADD AND TYPE "IIS_IUSRS" AND CLICK ON "Check Names".