# using Stream writer to Write a specific bytes to textfile

Tags: c#, text, stream, byte

Well I'm trying to write some values and strings to a text file.
but this text file must contain 2 bytes

These are the 2 bytes I want to insert to my text file after finishing writing the other values to it:

[image: hex]

I tried this method but I have no idea how to write bytes through it

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, false, Encoding.UTF8))
```

I have no idea about how to write them to the text file after putting the strings I want on it.

Comment: Have you tried `File.Open`?

Comment: It's not clear what these bytes are meant to mean, or what the rest of the text file is. Can you give us more context?

Comment: Are you trying to write UTF-16 text? Those two bytes may be the Byte Order Mark (BOM) for UTF-16 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16). In which case, try changing to Encoding.Unicode in your call, and I believe the framework will write the BOM for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save from SQL table to a text file Through Data Table and stream writer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402047/save-from-sql-table-to-a-text-file-through-data-table-and-stream-writer)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I recall correctly from your question. You want to write strings to a file and then write bytes to it?

This example will do that for you:

```
using (FileStream fsStream = new FileStream("Bytes.data", FileMode.Create))
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fsStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    // Writing the strings.
    writer.Write("The");
    writer.Write(" strings");
    writer.Write(" I");
    writer.Write(" want");
    writer.Write(".");

    // Writing your bytes afterwards.
    writer.Write(new byte[]
                 {
                     0xff,
                     0xfe
                 });
}
```

When opening the "Bytes.data" file with a hex editor you should see these bytes:
[image]

Comment: This worked fine, except that I had to use `writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foobar));` to prevent a `SUB` char at the beginning of the file. (`SUB` is what notepad++ showed as first character...)

Answer (score 30):

I just figured this out. It works quite well for me. The idea is you open the file with a FileStream that can write byte arrays, and put a StreamWriter on top of it to write strings. And then you can use both to mix strings with your bytes:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0xff, 0xfe };
writer.BaseStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: .BaseStream is what was needed to get under StreamWriter and send raw bytes

Answer (score 6):

Here is one more way to look for a solution...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("Hello!! ").Append(",");
sb.Append("My").Append(",");
sb.Append("name").Append(",");
sb.Append("is").Append(",");
sb.Append("Rajesh");
sb.AppendLine();

//use UTF8Encoding(true) if you want to use Byte Order Mark (BOM)
UTF8Encoding utf8withNoBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false);

byte[] bytearray;

bytearray = utf8withNoBOM.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/" + "MyFileName.csv"), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream, utf8withNoBOM);

    //StreamWriter for writing bytestream array to file document
    sw.BaseStream.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();

    fileStream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to write some strings to a text file, but you want to add 2 bytes to this file.

Why won't you try using: File.WriteAllBytes ?

Convert your string to a Byte array using

```
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str); // If your using UTF8
```

Create a new byte array from the original **byteArray** with the additional 2 bytes.

And write them to a file using:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("MyFile.dat", newByteArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `StreamWriter.Write(char)` that will write a 16-bit value.  You should be able to set your variable with the hex value like `char val = '\xFFFE'` and pass it to `Write`.  You could also use `FileStream` where all the Write methods work off bytes, and it specifically has a `WriteByte(byte)` method.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileStream%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for it gives an example of outputting UTF8 text.

Answer (score -1):

After saving the string simply write those bytes using for example using File.WriteAllBytes or a BinaryWriter:
[Can a Byte[] Array be written to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/can-a-byte-array-be-written-to-a-file-in-c)