# Save from SQL table to a text file Through Data Table and stream writer

Tags: c#, sql

thats my code

```
static void Write(DataTable dt, string outputFilePath)
        {
        int[] maxLengths = new int[dt.Columns.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            maxLengths[i] = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.Length;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNull(i))
                {
                    int length = row[i].ToString().Length;

                    if (length > maxLengths[i])
                    {
                        maxLengths[i] = length;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, false))
        {   
            sw.Write(new byte[]{0xff,0xfe});
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!row.IsNull(i))
                    {
                        sw.Write(row[i].ToString() + "  ");
                    }
                }

                sw.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

i want to put 2 bytes to the text file at the beginning.

```
sw.Write(new byte[]{0xff,0xfe});
```

the problem is when i open with hex i don't see those 2 bytes.
but i see on the text file itself these  [image: http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/1143/zaqj.png] :\

any solution please help.
its suppose to look like this [image: http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/1105/y40i.png]

Comment: Why do you want to write an UTF-16 BOM and then output the content as UTF-8? My guess is that the file should be UTF-16 and you should just use `new StreamWriter(..., Encoding.Unicode)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
sw.Write(new char[]{(char)0xff , (char)0xfe});
```

there is no implementaion of Write with array of byte in params : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write.aspx

so it use Object parameter and call his ToString() method

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/C1IKZQF.png

Comment: humm (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/x9h8tsay(v=vs.90).aspx) try with '\x00ff' and '\x00fe'

Comment: nope gived me weird value inside the text file "ÿþ"

Comment: and with (char)0xff , (char)0xfe ?