# How does Unity handle folders and files in exported games?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

I am quite new in game development with Unity and was wondering how the "export game" function of unity works. I not yet used this function in unity, but I've read that it will generate some .exe file from your complete game. I also read that it will create a "data" folder or something like that.

My question is: What exactly is stored in this "data" folder? And how can I write logic to save my own files (e.g. files which contain save states, settings, configurations, etc.) in some file inside this directory (which is then shipped with the complete game / created in the local game directory after the user e.g. saved his game the first time? Can i e.g. save those files in a relative path (e.g. ./MyGame/data/savegames)?

And which types of files can I create? Text / Binary? Or can I even use some relational Database (some small one like HSQLDB)?

And how are things like models, sounds, animations and other assets treated? Are they all packaged within the .exe file which is my complete game? Or do i have some seperate folders with the shipped game for them?

Thank you!

Comment: You can take a look at this tutorial : [Persistence - Saving and Loading Data](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data)

Comment: Thank you. Will have a look at it.

Comment: you should mark the correct answer dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data folder (named the same as the exe file, but `_Data` on the end instead of `.exe`, which [can be safely renamed to just Data](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/321932/renaming-the-data-folder.html)) contains [all of the dlls](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/541309/-data-folder.html) that actually run the game (even a blank Unity project will have them! The unity engine itself compiles to *several* dlls) as well as any [Resources](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) you might have (tip: stop using resources and use [Asset Bundles](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager) instead).

Omitting this folder would be very bad indeed!

As for reading/writing other data from the hard disk (which is not possible on all platforms--looking at you web deployment) I would recommend using your own folder, eg. `RuntimeData` which could contain external audio, image, or video files as well as mutable data such as [save games](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data) or screenshots. Pretty much anything you'd be ok with your users modifying without seriously breaking stuff (modding is "in" these days).

As for the *types* of file: well, that's up to you, really! Creating text files (of any extension: xml, html, dat, qqq...) is very easy.  Images tend to be done through a 3rd party script (do you *really* want to write your own JPG converter? Video, same thing).  You can also [create binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/can-a-byte-array-be-written-to-a-file-in-c) following a format of your own choosing. The only difficulty is writing the serializer and deserializer for the data, which would scale in difficulty as the complexity of the data scales.

You have full file system access* so you can realistically read or write anywhere.  This is C# we're talking about.  But with great power comes great responsibility.

*Note: Mobile devices heavily frown on that sort of thing and will deny access to folders outside the one explicitly given to that application.