# Just imports if the excel file into Database if it is in IIS express folder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

Well, I'm doing a program that imports data from an excel file into a database(sql server). The program runs fine if I save the excel file in IIS express folder but if I put in documents folder or something like it, it gives me an error:

here's the code:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        String strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HRD=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Name],[City],[Age] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
        excelConnection.Open();

        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


       // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       // SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [Name],[City],[Age] from [sheet1$]", strConnection);

        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);

        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Test";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
        excelConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What error....?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman :IErrorInfo.GetDescription com E_FAIL(0x80004005).

Comment: The process the IIS/Cassini runs under does not have permission to that folder. Consider writting the file to a folder with enough rights, doing the bulk copy, and deleting afterwards.

Comment: @bradbury9 Sorry for being ignorant, but I'm not understanding how im gonna do that...

Comment: Just check [Can a Byte Array be written to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/can-a-byte-array-be-written-to-a-file-in-c) and [How do I change folder and file Permissions?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed)

Comment: @bradbury9 I want to save in a folder like "files" to be able to upload in whatever the excel file is, into database (sql server) But the problem keeps showing me the error when I do not upload the file in IIS express folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
   string filepath = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Comment: it gave me this error The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'C:\Users\Pedro\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\123.xls'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'C:\Users\Pedro\source\repos\WebApplication5

Comment: Glad I could help! If my answer was helpful consider making it the accepted answer : )

Answer (score 0):

```
 string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/")Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
```