# How to convert a byte in pdf or jpg in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, base64

I have a base64 code and the name and extension of the file I convert it into byte using the following code

```
byte[] sPDFDecoded = Convert.FromBase64String(request.SetMcfile);

Code64="JVBERi0xLjcNCiWhs8XXDQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUiAvVHlwZS9DYXRhbG9nPj4NCmVuZG9iag0KMiAwIG9iag0KPDwvQ291bnQgMTUvS2lkc1sgNCAwIFIgIDIzIDAgUiAgNTEgMCBSICA1NyAwIFIgIDY0IDAgUiAgNzAgMCBSICA3NyAwIFIgIDgzIDAgUiAgOTAgMCBSICA5NiAwIFIgIDEwMyAwIFIgIDEwOSAwIFIgIDEy"

FileName = "Resumen.pdf"
```

I want to convert to the real file with the same name and the same extension to send it to an ftp server.

My method to save the file to ftp is as follows:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    long MaxSize = 10;

    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".pdf", ".jpeg" };

    if (!allowedExtensions[0].Equals(extension) && !allowedExtensions[1].Equals(extension) && !allowedExtensions[2].Equals(extension))
    {
        throw new ManejadorException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Los tipos de archivos permitidos son [.jpg, pdf]");
    }

    long fileSizeInBytes = file.Length;

    // Convert the bytes to Kilobytes (1 KB = 1024 Bytes)
    long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;

    // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
    long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;

    if (fileSizeInMB > MaxSize)
    {
        throw new ManejadorException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "El archivo supero el peso permitido 10MB");
    }

    // Create an FtpWebRequest
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://tiendashipi.com/" + file.FileName);

    // Set the method to UploadFile
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // Set the NetworkCredentials
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");

    // Set buffer length to any value you find appropriate for your use case
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
    byte[] fileContents;

    // Copy everything to the 'fileContents' byte array
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        int read;

        while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        fileContents = ms.ToArray();
    }

    // Upload the 'fileContents' byte array 
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        await requestStream.WriteAsync(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    }

    // Get the response
    // Some proper handling is needed
    var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    return response.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.FileActionOK;
}
```

Comment: `if (!allowedExtensions[0].Equals(extension) && !allowedExtensions[1].Equals(extension) && !allowedExtensions[2].Equals(extension))` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-5.0

Comment: `UploadFile` takes `IFormFile`, not a base64 string.

Comment: The question looks like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381508/can-a-byte-array-be-written-to-a-file-in-c... But that is totally useless for your `UploadFile` method as you actually need to create implementation of `IFormFile` for your `UploadFile` method as @mjwills said...

Comment: mjwills yes, that's why I want to convert the bytes to that data type